# My progress is stagnating and I don't want to disappoint my supervisor (Internship)

Tags: software-industry, internship, software-development

I don't know what I should do at the moment or what the best decision is at this point.

Through some contacts I got a nice internship in a country far away from home (I got recommended by my last supervisor).

I am helping a project team with a system that was developed by a 3rd party custom made for them. The original development team does not exist due to restructuring in the company. The people are still there but scattered throughout the company. The software (created in LabView) is not really documented. There are some issues with the software and it is not performing as it should.

My task now is to look into the software and the functions that it is executing and to evaluate if is it worth tinkering with the old code or writing something new in a different programming language (in this case python).

My situation is now that my internship is half over and my tests with python were quite unsuccessful. There is only one library that I could use me and the documentation on that is not as good as I hoped (last update 2016).

Also, I am still struggling to understand anything from the 3rd Party source code, because I never worked with this language and its different from anything I have encountered so far.

What should I do now? I can't decide and there is no other software developer around to help me and I really want to help the project by at least finishing something in the time I'm here. I need to write a small paper about my work here, but that is not really my concern at the moment.

Should I fully commit to creating a new small software project or should I invest all my time into getting along with the 3rd party code?

Thanks in advance for any advice or help!

Comment: Why are you asking these *good* questions random people on the internet? You should ask them your supervisor/mentor at the company. They should get a progress report from you and decide how to proceed.

Comment: the supervisor is super busy atm. because the project is in a critical phase with alot of demos etc. . Essentially I only get to talk with him every week or two for a few minutes and then he is gone again.

Comment: If an intern does not get the support they need, no sane person can expect good results from their work. So, disappointing the supervisor is not a concern. If they don't have time for a meeting, communicate it in writing (like you did in this question). Also tell them which of the two options you will chose if they don't provide feedback and then commit to it. That's the best you can do in such a (unfortunately quite common) situation.

Comment: Put it down in few paragraphs, stay on the point and ask one/two reasonably answerable questions. Email this to him just before the meeting and then make a 1 minute recap to him in person. He is the only one with a correct answer, definitely not us.

Comment: This is exactly a question your supervisor should answer.

Comment: Yesterday I informed my supervisor that I wanted to talk with him about my task. I also stressed that I wanted to discuss sth. and that it would be nice to have at least ~30 mins. He agreed and after the talk I will now fully focus my work erfrort into creating a small new software in python, I still think it is quite challenging but he also offered help if I still struggle with my current problem in the next few days. 

thanks for the fast responses and encouraging words!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask your supervisor.

They can give you the answers you are looking for. You will not disappoint them by asking what they want you to do.